# How much should one edit an edit?

Tags: discussion, editing, review-queue

Are there any established guidelines on how much one should intervene when reviewing an edit?

Specifically, when reviewing an edit with several grammatical corrections, but with similar errors left intact, if the first edit has improved the question and made it more readable, should I leave well enough alone?

That would be my likely approach, but the idea makes me twitchy.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If an edit has improved the question but left more improvement still to be done, then **by all means go ahead and do that improvement** - just as you would have done if you'd come across the question after the edit had been approved and noticed there was still more improvement to be done.

The system even goes out of its way to make it easier for you to do this:

[image]

There are not just buttons for **Approve** and **Reject** (the simplest possibilities), but also **Improve Edit** (which automatically approves the suggested edit, giving that user their +2 rep, and then puts you into the edit box so you can re-edit the edited version of the question) and **Reject and Edit** (which automatically rejects the suggested edit and puts you into the edit box so you can edit the original version of the question).

For more details on all facets of the suggesting and reviewing edits process, see [this post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/76284/278659) on main meta.

Comment: Thanks. I know about the buttons, but I was worried about trouncing on someone else's efforts. But I'm happy to take guidance on this. I'm still learning the norms here. I'll read the post.

Comment: @rosesunhill If you click "Improve Edit", you won't trounce anyone else's efforts - that only happens if you click "Reject and Edit" (or "Reject", of course).

Comment: @roseunhill We really only reject an edit if does nothing for the post, makes it worse, or drastically changes the meaning. I've personally also rejected a couple where they change the information (like a character's military rank) without adding citation somewhere.

Comment: The good thing about making the improvement straight away is that the question only gets bumped once.